# Как поле "Комментарий клиента" отправлять на почту Opencart 3.0?

Tags: php, opencart

Всем привет. Ребят, помогите. Сайт на Opencart версии 3.0.3.2 Суть в том, что при оформлении заказа клиент на Шаге 4: "Способ доставки" может оставить комментарий.
На почту этот комментарий не приходит.

Что нужно прописать в файлах:
catalog/model/checkout/order.php
и
catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/order_add.twig
чтобы этот комментарий приходил на почту?

В инете находил решения только для opencart версии 2. Но нужно именно для третьей версии.

Comment: С такими вопросами вам надо на фриланс разработчика искать т.к. очень многое зависит от темы, которая используется. Я бы рекомендовал посмотреть в каком "name" формы передается комментарий и дальше уже шел по обработчикам и моделям к отправке, проверяя где именно это значение теряется.

Comment: @AlexD Комментарий предназначен для админа и не дожен приходить клиенту. Коммента нет именно в письме к админу? Или вы хотите кастомизировать счёт, отсылаемый клиенту, и добавить туда его коммент?

Comment: Хочу, чтобы инфа в  поле "комментарий" приходило в письме клиенту. (Сделал костыль, чтобы письмо, которое приходит клиенту приходило и админу.)
Мне очень кажется, что это не от темы зависит (как написал adudnik.ru), так как это обрабатывается в стандартных файлах опенкарта, а зависит от версии CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Я установил сперва модуль
Admin Order same/detailed email as customer
[ссылка на Opencart MarketPlace](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&member_token=CPr6ui2FcimXnWIFNTTldgSl1PfT0ftS&extension_id=33659&filter_member=xtensions)

после я зашел в controller/mail/order.php
и перед строкой

```
if ($order_info['payment_address_format']) {
```

поставил следующую строку

```
if($order_info['comment']) $data['comment'] .= "<strong>". $data['text_comment'] . "</strong><br />" . strip_tags($order_info['comment']);
```

P.S. если не сработало советую в template/mail/order_add.twig
вписать все что ниже вместо того что там есть!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;">
<div style="width: 680px;"><a href="{{ store_url }}" title="{{ store_name }}"><img src="{{ logo }}" alt="{{ store_name }}" style="margin-bottom: 20px; border: none;" /></a>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;">{{ text_greeting }}</p>
  {% if customer_id %}
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;">{{ text_link }}</p>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="{{ link }}">{{ link }}</a></p>
  {% endif %}
  {% if download %}
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;">{{ text_download }}</p>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="{{ download }}">{{ download }}</a></p>
  <{% endif %}
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;" colspan="2">{{ text_order_detail }}</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><b>{{ text_order_id }}</b> {{ order_id }}<br />
          <b>{{ text_date_added }}</b> {{ date_added }}<br />
          <b>{{ text_payment_method }}</b> {{ payment_method }}<br />
          {% if shipping_method %} <b>{{ text_shipping_method }}</b> {{ shipping_method }}
          {% endif %}</td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><b>{{ text_email }}</b> {{ email }}<br />
          <b>{{ text_telephone }}</b> {{ telephone }}<br />
          <b>{{ text_ip }}</b> {{ ip }}<br />
          <b>{{ text_order_status }}</b> {{ order_status }}<br /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  {% if comment %}
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;">{{ text_instruction }}</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;">{{ comment }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  {% endif %}
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;">{{ text_payment_address }}</td>
        {% if shipping_address %}
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;">{{ text_shipping_address }}</td>
        {% endif %} </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;">{{ payment_address }}</td>
        {% if shipping_address %}
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;">{{ shipping_address }}</td>
        {% endif %} </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;">{{ text_product }}</td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;">{{ text_model }}</td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding: 7px; color: #222222;">{{ text_quantity }}</td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding: 7px; color: #222222;">{{ text_price }}</td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding: 7px; color: #222222;">{{ text_total }}</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    
    {% for product in products %}
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;">{{ product.name }}
        {% for option in product.option %}<br />
        &nbsp;<small> - {{ option.name }}: {{ option.value }}</small>{% endfor %}</td>
      <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;">{{ product.model }}</td>
      <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;">{{ product.quantity }}</td>
      <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;">{{ product.price }}</td>
      <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;">{{ product.total }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for voucher in vouchers %}
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;">{{ voucher.description }}</td>
      <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"></td>
      <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;">1</td>
      <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;">{{ voucher.amount }}</td>
      <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;">{{ voucher.amount }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    
    <tfoot>
    
    {% for total in totals %}
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;" colspan="4"><b>{{ total.title }}:</b></td>
      <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;">{{ total.text }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
      </tfoot>
    
  </table>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;">{{ text_footer }}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Пример как будет выглядеть комментарий в почте админа]